# ArcGIS Basemaps do not open

Tags: arcgis-online-basemaps

I am unable to open any new map. Add Data doesn't show any basemaps or Arcgis Online Maps. As soon as I try to add any of the base maps, my program closes on me.

Yet I am able to work on all my old saved maps with basemaps in them so far. Also, I can work with my database without adding any basemap or arcgis online maps.

To make a new map, the round about way I have figured out is to add a basemap from ArcCatalog/GIS servers/arcgis on services.arcgisonline.com

But I want my Add Data to add basemaps to my new maps.

How do I do that?

Comment: Is the program that you are using ArcMap, or something else?  When your program closes does it provide an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Without an error message or additional information, this is a bit difficult to troubleshoot, but I would suggest [this ESRI help link](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/31194) as a starting point. Highlights from that help link include:

Updating Java worked for some.

Clearing the cache worked for several:

> Try clearing your caches.  Go to the Display Cache tab in ArcMap
>   Options and choose Clear Cache.  Then try the basemaps again.

If on IE 10,

> In Internet Options (available through control panel or by clicking on
>   the settings button in IE 10), click on the "Connections" tab, then
>   click on the "LAN Settings" button. uncheck "Automatically detect
>   settings".

Sometimes an older graphics card causes this. To workaround:

> 1. Go to Customize-> ArcMap Options
> 2. Go to the Data View tab.
> 3. Uncheck "Enable Hardware Acceleration for supported layers.

If you're not up to date on service packs, try updating to SP 4:

> http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=66&MetaID=1843
>   and apply this patch ()
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=160&MetaID=1782